# Who and whom usage in single-word-sentence

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, whom

I know that if you say something with only one person—for example "Look over there, it's Jack"—the correct response is "who?" (short for "who is Jack?"), or at least I'm pretty sure this is true.

Anyway, what I am asking is whether you can differentiate between the object/subject of a statement using either *who* or *whom*. In other words, if someone said, for example, "George just hit Jack!", could you respond with either "Who?" or "Whom?" to specify whom you are referring to?

So if someone said, "George hit Jack", could you say "Who?" as in "Who (hit Jack)?" or "Whom?" as in "(George hit) Whom?" to specify whom you are referring to?

Thanks.

Comment: You *could* do that, but the percentage of the population who would understand it correctly is pretty small.  It’s much clearer to say either, ***Who?*** or ***Hit whom?***  or ***Who hit whom?*** depending on what you didn’t get the first time.

Comment: @Jim As Steven Littman says below, '... in ordinary conversational speech, "whom" is almost as dead as "thou" '. (I'd give prepositional phrases as an exception.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- Yep.  I have noticed that as well.  ***Who hit who?***  is also a viable option but I hesitated to introduce it in a “comment answer”

Answer (score 1):

Replying with just *Who?*, instead of *who is x?*, is colloquial. In a colloquial context, I would probably stick with *who*, whatever the original sentence. After all, you can ask *who is x?* about the object of a sentence just as well as about the subject. If you want to use *whom*, you should probably do so only in a full(er) sentence: *whom did Jack hit?* You could still use *whom* in a colloquial echo question, but then you'd still need a verb, as in *he hit whom? / hit whom?*

Comment: ...With a caveat that in ordinary conversational speech, "whom" is almost as dead as "thou".  Most people, even educated ones, would normally say "He hit who?" rather than "He hit whom?"

Comment: @Steven Littman Most people would ask '_Who_ did he hit?'

Comment: True, but what I said was in comparison with "he hit whom?" in the answer above.